# Clean `ChoiceField` from Django Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Model:

```
class SocialGroup(models.Model):
    INDIVIDUAL = 'individual'
    INSTITUTE = 'institute'
    options = ((INDIVIDUAL, 'Individual'),
               (INSTITUTE, 'Institute'))
    level = models.CharField(choices=options, max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

Form:

```
class GroupLevelForm(forms.Form):
    level = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SocialGroup.options)

    def clean_level(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['level']
```

When I call my form I do it like `level = GroupLevelForm({level: 'Individual'})`. I want `individual` back into cleaned data.

- I'm passing external name in my form how can I get back the internal name of the `choice field`.
- For example: `options = (('internal, 'External'),)` when I do it like `level = GroupLevelForm({level: 'External'})` how can I get `internal` in `cleaned_data`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is occurring because you don't call `is_valid()` on your form at any time. `cleaned_data` only exists once that has been called.

You want something along the lines of [pseudocode incoming]:

```
def clean_fields():
    if form.is_valid():
        self.cleaned_data['level']
```

Refer to the docs for django's explanation: [building a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django)

Comment: First of all, I apologize for the misleading info. Basically what I'm asking is if for the `choice field` I'm passing `external name` in my form how can I get back the `internal name` of the `choice field`. For example: `options = (('internal, 'External')` when I do it like `level = GroupLevelForm({level: 'External'})` how can I get `internal` in `cleaned_data`.

Comment: I have a feeling that if you change GroupLevelForm to a ModelForm class, it will take care of that for you.  Otherwise, you will probably end up having to take what you get from the cleaned_data and match it with the correct tuple in `options`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, I think you can do

```
def clean_level(self):
    selected_display_name = self.cleaned_data['level']
    for val, disp_name in SocialGroup.options:
        if disp_name == selected_display_name:
            return val
    return selected_display_name  # or whatever default you want
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @DevashishPatel if that solved your problem please mark that answer as the accepted answer so that the question is marked as solved in the list of questions. Thanks